# Combine different legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine legends of line graph and bar plot in my graph. I used the following code and I get the following output.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = profitCountries, aes(y = (revenue), x = residence, fill="revenue"), stat="identity", 
           color = "black") +

  geom_bar(data = profitCountries, aes(y= -(total_spend), x=residence, fill="total_spend"), stat="identity", 
           color = "black") +

  geom_line(data = profitCountries, aes(y = total_profit, x = residence, group = 1, color = "total_profit"), 
            size = 2 ) + 

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-500000,500000,100000), limits=c(-500000, 500000) ) +
  xlab('Countries') + ggtitle('Campaign spending and revenue by countries') + 
  ylab('Campaign spending                                     Revenue')  + theme_grey() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Name", values = c("revenue" = "darkgreen", "total_spend" = "red")) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "Name", values = c("total_profit" = "blue")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(), color = guide_legend())
```

[image]

Is there a way to combine both the legends where `total_profit`, `revenue` and `total_spend` all are in the same legend `Name`?

Comment: I would argue that doing so is basically incorrect. You are plotting two different types of information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there might be a better way...but one approach is to add `geom_blank` with an aesthetic that includes all 3 variables (`total_profit`, `revenue`, and `total_spend`). In addition, would make sure your `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual` have all/same combinations for values.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = profitCountries, aes(y = (revenue), x = residence, fill="revenue"), stat="identity", 
           color = "black") +

  geom_bar(data = profitCountries, aes(y= -(total_spend), x=residence, fill="total_spend"), stat="identity", 
           color = "black") +

  geom_line(data = profitCountries, aes(y = total_profit, x = residence, group = 1, color = "total_profit"), 
            size = 2 ) + 

  geom_blank(data = data.frame(group = c("revenue", "total_spend", "total_profit")), 
             aes(color = group, fill = group)) +

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-500000,500000,100000), limits=c(-500000, 500000) ) +
  xlab('Countries') + ggtitle('Campaign spending and revenue by countries') + 
  ylab('Campaign spending                                     Revenue')  + theme_grey() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Name", values = c("revenue" = "darkgreen", "total_spend" = "red", "total_profit" = NA)) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "Name", values = c("revenue" = NA, "total_spend" = NA, "total_profit" = "blue")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(), color = guide_legend())
```

Alternatively, you could include `color` in the `aes` for both `geom_bar` and adding `fill` to your `geom_line` (with `fill` attribute getting ignored not being appropriate). Ideally you would have consistent use of `color` and `fill` across all of your geometries. And (ideally) you would not be combining these two different geometries together in this case.